# Send Iplimage data as jpeg

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to send Iplimage to another program as a array of bytes in c++/cli. The program needs to save the Iplimage as jpeg image. Let's say the Iplimage is img which I am obtaing by cvQyeryFrame from an avi video file, I am returning img->imagedata to the other program. Does img->imagedata contain the header for the jpeg image to be saved or does it only contain the data. If it only contains the data, how can I include the header? I can save the image using cvSaveImage and then read it but there should be a more direct way (maybe cvEncodeImage? )

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the Iplimage is already decoded into own format of openCV (typically 8bit B,G,R) once it has been read from disk.

The newer versions of opencv can encode/decode an image in memory, see [imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode).

Comment: The other program is C# and does not have OpenCv. Can the other C# program save the encoded image as a jpg without having to use imdecode?

Comment: Once the jpeg is encoded it's a standard jpeg. It can be decoded by any jpeg lib that can read from a block of bytes

Answer (score 1):

If you need the entire JPEG data, you might want to consider reading the entire file from the disk with `fread()` instead of `cvLoadImage()`.

If that's not going to work for you, consider Martin's answer.